# Nested Strong Params with arrays and hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I can almost get everything I need from these params (which I've simplified)

```
h = { "rate"=>{
        "destination"=>{
        "country"=>"US", "postal_code"=>"12345", "province"=>"NC",
        "city"=>"Charlotte", "name"=>"mine", "address1"=>"12 Main"
      },
      "items"=>[
        {
          "name"=>"Buy This", "sku"=>"MC-J4", "quantity"=>1,
          "fulfillment_service"=>"web", "properties"=>nil,
          "variant_id"=>13992832794667
        }
      ],
      "currency"=>"USD",
      "locale"=>"en"
    } 
  }
```

This is what I have so far:

```
params.permit(:domain, :type, rate: [destination: {}, items: [:name, :sku, :quantity, :fulfillment_service]])
```

What I'm missing is the `currency` value. I've tried the following with no luck:

```
params.permit(:domain, :type, rate: [destination: {:currency}, items: [:name, :sku, :quantity, :fulfillment_service]])

params.permit(:domain, :type, rate: [destination: {}, items: [:name, :sku, :quantity, :fulfillment_service], :currency])
```

And many more similar iterations. Some reason I can't get that `currency` value. Any help??

Comment: I'm sure this a duplicate but they can be hard to find. Anyway, "to permit a hash, pass an array; to permit an array, pass a hash" so I think you want `destination: [:currency]` (or equivalently `destination: %i[currency]`).

Comment: I've edited the hash so that it's structure can be more easily seen. I've also set it equal to a local variable (`h`) should readers want to reference that.

Comment: Try `params.permit(:domain, :type, rate: [:currency, destination: {}, items: [:name, :sku, :quantity, :fulfillment_service]])`

Comment: @Pavan thank you! that worked, I swear I had tried that before!! if you'd like to get credit put yours as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work

```
params.permit(:domain, :type, rate: [:currency, destination: {}, items: [:name, :sku, :quantity, :fulfillment_service]])
```